# How to get correct reference variable value in Angular 2 (TypeScript)?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 (TypeScript).

I have a class which looks like this:

```
class Device{
    id:string;
    label:string;
}
```

I want to show device label in dropdown list, but in onChange() I want to get device ID. What can I do? Thank you!

```
<select #device (change)="onChange($event, device.value)">
    <option *ng-for="#i of devices.label">{{i}}</option>
</select>

onChange($event, deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
    // Right now deviceValue is device label, however I want to get device ID.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a binding to a [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html#option.attrs.value) property of an `<option>` (`[value]="device.id"`). See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DhK2TuNu8ctTheAYttup?p=preview):

```ts
import {Component, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [NgFor],
  template: `
    <select #device (change)="onChange($event, device.value)">
      <option *ng-for="#device of devices" [value]="device.id">
        {{ device.label }}
      </option>
    </select>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.devices = [
      { id: 1, label: 'Nokia'    },
      { id: 2, label: 'Motorola' },
      { id: 3, label: 'iPhone'   }
    ]
  }

  onChange(event, deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, alexpods, especially the link to W3!